# Best practice to use double arrays

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, android-ndk

I trying to write MINPACK-Fortran port for Android and I can't understand the proper use of double arrays in JNI. Studying the question on the forums, I realized that the JNI requires a large amount of useless code when working with arrays. I would like to be wrong, so bring the code here.

In this example, there is a call of procedure **hybrd1_** (Fortran sub, provided by MINPACK) to calculate systems of nonlinear equations.
The user (Java side) provides class aSolver, which contains method *solveStep*. *solveStep* has two parametres (arrays of double) where x - vector of parametres; f - vector of right-side in NLES. The problem is that I don't know what vectors are transmitted by the **hybrd1_** procedure into the *solveStep*, while the iteration continues. But i know, that these vectors can be find inside x, fvec, or wa (the fields inside aSolver object).
**hybrd1_** calls the **rhs** procedure (cdecl) - procedure where are a lot of terrible things i need to do to transfer two arrays to Java, then to bring them back to c++. As you can see the **rhs** procedure calling very frequently and these JNI conversions are breaking down the entire procedure.

**C++ side**

```
//struct which allow me to talk with Java from rhs procedure
struct fake_n
{
    int n;
    jobject aSolver;
    jmethodID meth;
    JNIEnv* env;
};

//iterator. the place where i need help
void rhs(int * n, double * x, double * f, int * flag)
{
    fake_n* f_n = (fake_n *) n;
    // creating array parametres 
    jdoubleArray x_row = ((*f_n).env)->NewDoubleArray((*f_n).n);
    jdoubleArray f_row = ((*f_n).env)->NewDoubleArray((*f_n).n);
    // filling array parametres 
    ((*f_n).env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(x_row, 0, (*f_n).n, x);
    // launch object method
    (*f_n).env->CallVoidMethod((*f_n).aSolver, (*f_n).meth, x_row, f_row);
    // copy result back to c++ - why do i need? 
    jdouble *res = ((*f_n).env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(f_row, NULL);
    for (int i =0; i< (*f_n).n; i++) { f[i] = res[i]; }        
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_hybrd_1NLES(JNIEnv* env,
                                                            jclass clazz,
                                                            jobject aSolver)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(aSolver);
    jmethodID solvestep = env->GetMethodID(cls, "solveStep", "([D[D)V");
    if (solvestep == 0) {
        return;
    }

    jfieldID afields[4];
    char* atype[4] = {(char *) "[I", (char *)"[D", (char *)"[D", (char *)"[D"};
    char* aname[4] = {(char *)"n", (char *)"x", (char *)"fvec", (char *)"wa"};
    jobject objs[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        afields[i] = env->GetFieldID(cls, aname[i], atype[i]);
        objs[i] = env->GetObjectField(aSolver, afields[i]);
    }
    jintArray *na = reinterpret_cast<jintArray *>(&(objs[0]));
    jdoubleArray *xa = reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray *>(&(objs[1]));
    jdoubleArray *fveca = reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray *>(&(objs[2]));
    jdoubleArray *waa = reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray *>(&(objs[3]));

    int *n = env->GetIntArrayElements(*na, NULL);
    double *x = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*xa, NULL);
    double *fvec = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*fveca, NULL);
    double *wa = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*waa, NULL);

    fake_n f_n;
    f_n.n = *n;
    f_n.aSolver = aSolver;
    f_n.meth = solvestep;
    f_n.env = env;

    // tol, lwa, info - local variables
    // this procedure calls the iterator (rhs) a lot of times   
    hybrd1_(rhs, (int *)&f_n, x, fvec, &tol, &info, wa, &lwa);

    // should i ?
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(*na, n, 0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(*xa, x, 0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(*fveca, fvec, 0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(*waa, wa, 0);
}
```

**And here is the JAVA side**

```
public class aSolver {
    public double[] x;
    public double[] fvec;
    public double[] wa;
    public int[] n;
    public int rc;

    public aSolver() {
        n = new int[1];
        n[0] = 2;
        x = new double[n[0]];
        fvec = new double[n[0]];
        wa = new double[n[0] * (3 * n[0] + 13) / 2];
        x[0] = 0;
        x[1] = 1;
        rc = 0;
        solveStep(x, fvec);
    }

    // method, which calling from iterator (rhs)
    public void solveStep(double[] xv, double[] fv ) {
        // it is important: fv != fvec
        // it is important: xv != x
        fv[0] = 2.0 * xv[0] + 3.0 * xv[1] + 6.0;
        fv[1] = 5.0 * xv[0] - 3.0 * xv[1] - 27.0;
        rc++;
    }
}

//----
aSolver s = new aSolver();
hybrd_NLES(s);
//----

public native void hybrd_NLES(aSolver solver);
```

Written code seems cumbersome and inefficient. Moreover, there is a feeling that the **rhs** sub needs in **ReleaseDoubleArrayElements**, but I do not understand why it needed there. Please help me to write an efficient wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JNI code is indeed cumbersome by definition, since you have to use the 'env' to create certain variables, and you have to do some coding for getting the data you need with the Java code and to communicate with it.
I cannot really say how to make your code more efficient, since I do not really understand what you wanted to do. You may have some unnecessary copying, I'm not sure. If you review you code and still think you can improve it, explain a bit further what is your goal.
Regarding your question on 'ReleaseDoubleArrayElements' - NewDoubleArray creates a local reference only, so you do not need to release it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation about ReleaseDoubleArrayElements. What about "unnecessary copying"? I have added additional comments in the code

Comment: Before your last edit, it looked like there are some unnecessary operations, but looking at it now - it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution and I place it here, if someone has a similar problem.  I place all the working arrays in one and pass it to C++ from Java. Then inside **rhs** I calculate the memory offsets to vectors x and f and bring them in *solveStep* (now I am sending to Java only offsets).
Here is changed code:

**C++ side**

```
struct fake_n
{
    int n;

    jobject aSolver;
    jmethodID meth;
    JNIEnv* env;
    double* dbls;
};

void rhs(int * n, double * x, double * f, int * flag)
{
    fake_n* f_n = (fake_n *) n;
    // calculate the offsets to x and f vectors
    jint x_row = (jint)(x - (*f_n).dbls);
    jint f_row = (jint)(f - (*f_n).dbls);
    // and call the method of aSolver object
    (*f_n).env->CallVoidMethod((*f_n).aSolver, (*f_n).meth, x_row, f_row);
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_hybrd_1NLES(JNIEnv* env,
                                                            jclass clazz,
                                                            jobject aSolver)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(aSolver);
    jmethodID solvestep = env->GetMethodID(cls, "solveStep", "(II)V");
    if (solvestep == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int info = 0;

    //JNIlist - helper class to connect to JNI and to hold the variables data
    //nothing unusual - jast a couple of simple wrappers
    //original code is shown above
    JNIlist * lJNI = new JNIlist(env, aSolver, cls);
    lJNI->add(JNI_DT_INT,          (char *)"n");
    lJNI->add(JNI_DT_DOUBLE_ARRAY, (char *)"dbls");
    lJNI->connectJNI();

    int n = *((int*)lJNI->data(0));
    int lwa = n * (3 * n + 13) / 2 + 1;
    double tol = rel_TOL;

    fake_n f_n;
    f_n.n = n;
    f_n.aSolver = aSolver;
    f_n.meth = solvestep;
    f_n.env = env;
    f_n.dbls = (double*)(lJNI->data(1)); //pointer to the REAL memory section
    // with the array of doubles "dbl" 
    //cause GetDoubleArrayElements with the iCopy parameter which equals JNI_FALSE
    // gives access to the real memory section

    hybrd1_(rhs, (int *)&f_n, f_n.dbls, f_n.dbls + n, &tol, &info, f_n.dbls + 2*n, &lwa);

    delete lJNI;

    return info;
}
```

**Java side**

```
public class aSolver {
    public double[] dbls;
    public int lwa;
    public int n;
    public int info;
    public int rc;
    private int xoffset, foffset;

    public aSolver() {
        n = 2;
        lwa = (n*(3 * n + 13)/2 + 1);
        dbls = new double[2 * n + lwa];
        info = 0;
        dbls[0] = 0;
        dbls[1] = 1;
        rc = 0;
        solveStep(0, 1);
    }

    public void setOffsets(int xv, int fv ) {
        xoffset = xv;
        foffset = fv;
    }

    public void setf(int p, double val){
        dbls[foffset + p] = val;
    }

    public double x(int p){
        return dbls[xoffset + p];
    }

    public void solveStep(int xv, int fv ) {
        setOffsets(xv, fv);
        setf(0, 2.0 * x(0) + 3.0 * x(1) + 6.0);
        setf(1, 5.0 * x(0) - 3.0 * x(1) - 27.0);
        rc++;
    }
}
```